# Old movie where a scientist clones his daughter

Tags: story-identification, movie

A scientist in his cellar lab creates a clone of his deceased daughter, in a giant egg.

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, what else can you remember about the movie, was it colour/BW, how old was it (from the 60's, 70's, 80's, 90's etc...  Welcome and see if there is anything else you can add to this post to help us give you an answer :)

Comment: Not old but reminds me of the fantastic thrill ride that is Replicas, starring keanu reeves, though the egg is a science thingamybob: Following a tragic car accident, William Foster, a scientist, desperately tries to bring his wife and children back from the dead, and spends a fair bit of time hiding that they were cloned in his basement.

Comment: Replicas was so bootleg I can't believe Keanu agreed to be a part of that. lmao!

Comment: Sounds a bit like DEMON SEED (1977). The incubator looks kinda like an egg and the twist at the end of the film is that, yup, it was a clone of the deceased daughter.

Comment: Demon seed it is!! Thank you Cassfrank!!

Comment: @Cassfrank it's your turn now =)

Answer (score 7):

As confirmed by the OP (Colette) in the comments section, this is DEMON SEED  (1977). Adapted from Dean Koontz's novel and centers around:

> the imprisonment and forced impregnation of a woman by an artificially intelligent computer.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed)

The moment asked about comes at the end when it is revealed that the baby born from the egg-like incubator is a clone.